# Javascript, несложный вопрос про методы и свойства

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект person, в нем на момент создания нет свойства age, но есть метод, который это свойство добавляет. И пока я этот метод не вызвал свойства там не будет. На строке 69 я вывожу в консоль этот метод, и там уже есть свойство age, хотя метод я вызываю после вывода в консоль метода. Я полагал, что до момента вывоза метода calculateAge() его там не должно быть. Вопрос, это так и должно быть или это результат обработки кода babel и webpack? И если так и должно быть, то почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дмытрык, вопрос такой же, действительно, но мне сложно было сформулировать его грамотно и понятно,  поэтому я не нашел ответа при поиске. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри внимательнее на свой скриншот. На момент первого вывода многоточия нет. а значит нет и свойства `age`. А после уже есть. А вот развёрнутый объект просматривается в момент разворачивания, а тогда свойство там уже есть.

Если хочешь вывести замороженный (на один уровень) объект, используй `cosole.table`.

[image: скриншот]